# Adding an integer to C-String while printing

Tags: c, string, printf

```
  int main(){
printf("hello world"+2);
```

}

```
test.c:32:25: warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string
      [-Wstring-plus-int]
    printf("hello world"+2);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
test.c:32:25: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
    printf("hello world"+2);
                        ^
           &            [ ]
1 warning generated.
alpha@Desktop % ./a.out   
llo world%
```

So this is what I am getting. And if I increase the number then it is simply slicing the string by that.Can anyone explain this output and why it's happening to me?

Comment: Did you want `printf("Hello world %i\n", 2);`?

Comment: Follow a basic C tutorial before you start applying your knowledge of other languages. It does not work like that.

Comment: rohanrudra55, what output were your hoping for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C and C++ languages, every string that has been defined with double quotes is of type `char*` (pointer to char) as a statically allocated char array. When you call `printf()` on such string it does something like this:

```cpp
void printf(char* str) {
    while(*str!= '\0') {
        // write the current character to stdout
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, sizeof(char));
        str ++;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it really is written that way, indeed it probably isn't, the functionality is the same. It iterates over the string until it finds the null-terminator (`'\0'`). All pointers are almost equivalent to `long` and when you add a number to them, it increments their underlying value with `sizeof(type)`, where type is the type of value the pointer points towards. Thus, when you add a number to "Hello World", makes `printf()` think your string starts on a different memory address and prints 'llo World'.

If you want to print the string with the value '2' appended to the end of it, as @Elliott Frisch stated, you would use `print("Hello World%d", 2)`.

I would suggest looking at `sprintf()` and `strcat()` for string concatenation in C.

Comment: Technically a string literal has type `char[N + 1]` ... which, in many contexts (being used as the *format string* in `printf()` or in an addition expression with an `int` are two such contexts), gets converted to a `char *`.

Answer (score 2):

In C, what we might think of as a *string* is actually an array of characters. What you pass to `printf()` in both cases is a *pointer* to the start of such an array. You can do arithmetic with pointers, which is what you are doing here.

Here's some clarification.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // A
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    // B
    printf("Hello, world!\n" + 2);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
llo, world!
```

In **case A**, you point to the start of an array containing the `H` character, and it reads until the last one (which is in fact a 'this is the end'-character: `\0`).

| ⬇️ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H | e | l | l | o | , |  | w | o | r | l | d | ! | `\n` | `\0` |

In **case B**, you add 2 to the pointer before passing it to `printf()`. Now `printf()` starts reading here:

|  |  | ⬇️ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H | e | l | l | o | , |  | w | o | r | l | d | ! | `\n` | `\0` |

This is what causes your 'slice'.

Comment: I really like this explanation; the diagrams make it very clear what's going on.